# How to edit AutoCAD Layer Description using ezdxf

Tags: python-3.x, autocad, dxf

I want to know how to edit AutoCAD's Layer Description property.

I have referenced the ezdxf documentation but I do not know how.

Please tell me an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Layer Description in AutoCAD is stored within the Extended Entity Data (xData) of the Layer Table record, associated with the second occurrence of DXF group 1000 under the `AcAecLayerStandard` Application ID.

As such, you should be able to configure the layer description using ezdxf using something along the lines of the following:

```
import ezdxf

dwg = ezdxf.readfile('C:\YourFilename.dxf')
lay = dwg.layers.get('YourLayerHere')
app = 'AcAecLayerStandard'
dsc = 'YourDescriptionHere'

if lay.tags.has_xdata(app):
    lay.tags.set_xdata(app, [(1000, ''), (1000, dsc)])
else:
    dwg.appids.new(app)
    lay.tags.new_xdata(app, [(1000, ''), (1000, dsc)])
```

The above is entirely untested.

Comment: I'm sorry. Another question.
If it is already in the layer description, how can I add it to it?

Comment: Retrieve the current value associated with the second DXF group 1000 entry within the xdata for the `AcAecLayerStandard` application ID, concatenate your description to the start or end of it, and then modify the xdata using the method demonstrated above.

Comment: Thank you.
Sorry to trouble you, but can you tell me the code?

Comment: changes in upcoming ezdxf v0.10 - `tags` attribute do not exist anymore, but algorithm works as shown, just remove `tags`: `lay.new_xdata(...)`; added `description` property to layer table entry to get/set layer description (also for `transparency`)